# Create contact group in EWS in contact folder other than WellKnownFolderName.Contact

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm creating a job to import contacts from a web system to exchange. I'm importing the contacts to their own folder. I'd like to be able to add them to groups within that folder. I have created groups and added contacts to them, but cannot figure out how to get the groups to show in any folder other than the default WellKnownFolderName.Contacts. Here is my code to create the contact group, looks like parentid is a readonly property, is it possible to do this?

```
  public static ContactGroup CreateContactGroup(string distributionList, ExchangeService service, FolderId folder)
    {
        try
        {
            ContactGroup cg = new ContactGroup(service);
            cg.DisplayName = distributionList;
            cg.Save();
            return cg;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Contact Group in another contacts Folder you need to get the FolderId of that Folder and then use that in the Save Overload eg if you have a Contacts Folder under contacts called OtherContacts you can use something like this to find and then create the ContactGroup in that folder

```
        FolderView cfv = new FolderView(1000);
        cfv.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Shallow;
        SearchFilter cfFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName,"OtherContacts");
        FolderId cntfld = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, "mailbox@domain.com");
        FindFoldersResults ffcResult = service.FindFolders(cntfld, cfFilter, cfv);
        if (ffcResult.Folders.Count == 1) {
            ContactGroup cg = new ContactGroup(service);
            cg.DisplayName = "TestCg";
            cg.Save(ffcResult.Folders[0].Id);
        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: This worked... Already had the folder id so I didn't need any of the search code, but I'm sure it will help others :-) Thanks for the help